# APEX: Redirect after login to a page with arguments

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-apex

this in the normal login proccess page

`wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login(
    P_UNAME       => :P101_USERNAME,
    P_PASSWORD    => :P101_PASSWORD,
    P_SESSION_ID  => v('APP_SESSION'),
    P_FLOW_PAGE   => :APP_ID||':1'
    );`

that redirects to page 1, my problem is that i want to redirect to page 1 but i want to pass some values like CURRENT_NODE_ID,P1_ID width zero like the example above

`f?p=104:1:708914681153727:::CIR:CURRENT_NODE_ID,P1_ID:0,0`

is this possible to do in wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login function? or is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please, use tag "oracle-apex" on Oracle Application Express questions, since "apex" is the ambiguous tag. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73007/tag-overlap-oracle-apex-and-apex-visualforce. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the values via the URL. You can modify the authentication scheme to set those values when a user logs in. For example:

In your chosen Authentication Scheme, set **Post-Authentication Process** to:

```
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('CURRENT_NODE_ID', 0);
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P1_ID', 0);
```

I generally do this in a database procedure and place a call to it in the Authentication Scheme - which is why I'm using APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE. I haven't tried it but this might also work in this field:

```
:CURRENT_NODE_ID := 0;
:P1_ID := 0;
```

**EDIT**

To modify your Authentication Scheme (these instructions are for Apex 4, but they should be much the same for earlier versions):

1. Go to the **Application Builder**
2. Open the application you wish to modify
3. Go to **Shared Components**
4. Select **Authentication Schemes**
5. Open the current Authentication Scheme
6. Scroll down to **Login Processing**
7. Place your code in the **Post-Authentication Process**

Comment: Can you explain how do you do the authentication scheme and where, i'm not understanding where can i put the `APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('CURRENT_NODE_ID', 0);
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P1_ID', 0);`                                                        Tanks

Comment: I think i found out how its done i put that in the Get Username Cookie in `declare
    v varchar2(255) := null;
    c owa_cookie.cookie;
begin
   c := owa_cookie.get('LOGIN_USERNAME_COOKIE');
   :P101_USERNAME := c.vals(1);
   :CURRENT_NODE_ID := 0;
   :P1_ID := 0;
exception when others then null; end;`

Comment: more detailed instructions added.