# APEX: Redirect after login to a page with arguments: Part Deux

Tags: oracle-apex

In a similar vein to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117050/apex-redirect-after-login-to-a-page-with-arguments), we have a page that's accessed by passing some parameters via the URL.

`f?p=103:3:::::P3_EQUIPMENT:EQUIPMENT_X`

Unlike the mentioned question, the value of the parameter is not fixed. So the problem we are experiencing is when the login page is called, the `P3_EQUIPMENT` value is lost, and not set when the authentication is performed. Since we cannot know ahead of time what the value may be, I'm not sure if the set session state solution applies here.

Are there any recommended solutions?

Comment: What is the source of value which you want to pass (user input, calculation, url parameter, etc)? In any case, you can use that solution, but process source of value first.

Comment: The APEX page we're using is part of a larger solution -- built upon Sharepoint and Silverlight technologies -- but we are limited in what we can do with them. Specifically, the Sharepoint pages build the APEX URIs and substitute the values for the parameter from another control. This allows the APEX page to change it's data based on the values of the parameter passed in.

Comment: You shouldn't get that problem unless you have Deep Linking set to Disabled in the security tab for your application - in which case you will always be sent to the home page after login.  With Deep Linking enabled a URL like yours should work as expected.

Comment: @Tony you're right. looking further into what was developed, it appears that there was a `owa_util.redirect_url` in the page sentry function that was interfering. Disabling the page sentry made it behave exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: I suggest setting a global item P0_EQUIPMENT_X, and when linking use: f?p=103:3:::::P3_EQUIPMENT:&P0_EQUIPMENT_X;